# How to make TFS project (version control) read only?

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2013.

1. I need to make a project as read only, so that no new code/items can be added to the projects. Please advice.
2. Also, please let me know if there is a way to make only either of workitems or code as readonly.

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried and what is not working for you?

Answer (score -3):

These options are both possible and are described as part of the MSDN documentation for TFS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587.aspx